# Button bar above or below android application

Tags: android

How could i put a `Button` bar at the top or bottom of my android application?

That is, in the `Activities` of my application I want the `Button` bar in all of them.

A bar with quick access `Buttons` (a button Home, another Exit button ... etc)

How can this be implemented?

thank you very much

Comment: I would strongly consider using the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for this user paradigm. Also, an 'exit' button does not really make sense in Android app, but that's up to you of course.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `RelativeLayout` you can place `Views` that are at the bottom of the parent `View` or the top of the parent `View`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="left top of parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="right top of parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="left bottom of parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="right bottom of parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can create a new class for that button bar and include that UI element in all your screens. The concept is called fragment. If you change code for fragment once it will be reflected on all other screens.
[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments) is tutorial on fragments.